# Key map and vector key sequence

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, paredit

**paredit.el** has the following example code for setting a keybinding:

https://github.com/emacsmirror/paredit/blob/8330a41e8188fe18d3fa805bb9aa529f015318e8/paredit.el#L54

```el
    (eval-after-load 'paredit
      '(progn
         (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "ESC M-A-C-s-)")
           'paredit-dwim)))
```

Evaluating `(kbd "ESC M-A-C-s-)")` outputs `[27 213909545]`.

How to interpret this vector key sequence. What keys does this represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the doc string of `kbd` (`C-h f kbd)`), it mentions that there is an approximate inverse function called `key-description`. If you apply this function to the vector, you get

```
(key-description [27 213909545])
"ESC A-C-M-s-)"
```

Note the different order!

The explanation is that these represent [modifier keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Other-Char-Bits.html): that's ESC followed by the key combination `ALT-CONTROL-META_SUPER-)` i.e. you have to hold all of those modifier keys down while you press the closing paren key. That also explains why the order of the modifiers does not matter, so `kbd` and `key-description` can list them in different orders.

Since, AFAICT, `paredit-dwim` does not exist as a function, and since most keyboards define some but not all of these modifier keys (making it impossible to press that combination unless you use something like `xmodmap` to define all the modifiers), I can only assume that the example is meant as tongue-in-cheek.